add a horizontal line in a ggplot Likert bar
I have a ggplot object named p :
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

likert_levels <- c(
  "Strongly disagree",
  "Disagree",
  "Neither agree nor disagree",
  "Agree",
  "Strongly agree"
)

df <-
  tibble(
    "there is an argument sort_prop_include_center that could be set up to TRUE in order to include half of the centered level when sorting data" = sample(likert_levels, 150, replace = TRUE),
    "Similarly, the argument totals_include_center allows you to include half of the centered level into the left and the right totals" = sample(likert_levels, 150, replace = TRUE, prob = 5:1),
    "Here is one possible option which uses reorder and an ifelse to reorder the variable mapped on y using the counts (aka the sum) of Strictly disagree " = sample(likert_levels, 150, replace = TRUE, prob = 1:5),
    "and disagree answers. Under the hood ggstats::gglikert reshape the data to long where the question id's are stored in a column named .question and the answers in a column named .answer:" = sample(likert_levels, 150, replace = TRUE, prob = 1:5),
    "They used sampling data and create a data frame called df. I am using the same as given in the link.(the df not the df_dk). Ok, if i run in R the following code :" = sample(c(likert_levels, NA), 150, replace = TRUE),
    "proportion of answers higher than the centered level. I want the plot to be sorted according to very left proportions that are the combination (sum) of the two lower levels. (i.e Respectively the percentages on the very right in the sum of the two lower categories. )" = sample(likert_levels, 150, replace = TRUE, prob = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0))
  ) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ factor(.x, levels = likert_levels)))



library(ggplot2)
library(ggstats)

p = ggstats::gglikert(df) +
  aes(y = reorder(.question,
                  ifelse(
                    .answer %in% c("Strongly disagree", "Disagree"),
                    1, 0
                  ),
                  FUN = sum
  ))+ theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8))

I want to add horizontally two lines:

line that will separate the y axis as now is sorted in a decreasing order at 20% and

a second line at 50 %.


additionally I want a text from 0 to 20% to write "warning zone" inside the panel (plot) at the left and from 20% to 50% "so-so" and from 50% to 100% to write "no warning zone"
How can I achieve this using ggplot2 package in R  in this sorted scale Likert plot ?

Do you mean "warning zone" for the bottom bar because it's only 19% disagree, "so-so" for the middle four bars, and "no warning zone" for the top bar (63% disagree)?

@Carl the plot is sorted with decreasing order based on the sum of the percentages of the two lower categories at the left of the middle category.So I want a horizontal line at 20%.Yes 19% will fall in the warning zone.The next line to be at the 50%.

To determine the position of the lines and text, save the original plot as p, then use layer_data(p, 3) to inspect the data (specifically the x, y and label columns) behind the 3rd ggplot layer (the one with the text percentages).
Then add the geom_hline and annotates with the determined positions.
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstats)
library(purrr)

likert_levels <- c(
  "Strongly disagree",
  "Disagree",
  "Neither agree nor disagree",
  "Agree",
  "Strongly agree"
)

df <-
  tibble(
    "there is an argument sort_prop_include_center that could be set up to TRUE in order to include half of the centered level when sorting data" = sample(likert_levels, 150, replace = TRUE),
    "Similarly, the argument totals_include_center allows you to include half of the centered level into the left and the right totals" = sample(likert_levels, 150, replace = TRUE, prob = 5:1),
    "Here is one possible option which uses reorder and an ifelse to reorder the variable mapped on y using the counts (aka the sum) of Strictly disagree " = sample(likert_levels, 150, replace = TRUE, prob = 1:5),
    "and disagree answers. Under the hood ggstats::gglikert reshape the data to long where the question id's are stored in a column named .question and the answers in a column named .answer:" = sample(likert_levels, 150, replace = TRUE, prob = 1:5),
    "They used sampling data and create a data frame called df. I am using the same as given in the link.(the df not the df_dk). Ok, if i run in R the following code :" = sample(c(likert_levels, NA), 150, replace = TRUE),
    "proportion of answers higher than the centered level. I want the plot to be sorted according to very left proportions that are the combination (sum) of the two lower levels. (i.e Respectively the percentages on the very right in the sum of the two lower categories. )" = sample(likert_levels, 150, replace = TRUE, prob = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0))
  ) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ factor(.x, levels = likert_levels)))

# function to save retyping common arguments
anno <- partial(annotate, "text", x = -1, angle = 90, size = 5, fontface = "bold")

gglikert(df) +
  aes(y = reorder(.question,
                  ifelse(
                    .answer %in% c("Strongly disagree", "Disagree"),
                    1, 0
                  ),
                  FUN = sum, decreasing = TRUE
  )) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8)) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(1.5, 5.5), linetype = "dashed", colour = "grey20") +
  anno(y = 1, label = "warning\nzone", color = "#A6611A") +
  anno(y = 3.5, label = "so-so", color = "black") +
  anno(y = 6, label = "no warning\nzone", color = "#018571") +
  labs(y = NULL)


Created on 2024-04-21 with reprex v2.1.0

Yes works fine.But how you choose yintercept to be the vector 1.5 ,5.5 and y to be 1 3.5 or 6? I am asking out of curiosity.I mean how?

The y-axis is categorical, so simply has values 1 to 6. You can see this if you save the original plot as p, then run layer_data(p, 3) which shows the data behind the 3rd ggplot layer (specifically the y column). So the warning zone is only 1 (label column is 19%) and the line goes at 1.5, i.e. between 1 and 2.

layer_data(p, 3) also told me the x position of your left-most text labels, i.e. -0.82 and therefore where to position the zone text.

My apologies.I now saw it.The plot must be sorted the opposite.I.e when the sum of the two lower categories are greater than 50 to be warning zone.from 50 to 20 so-so and from 20 to 0 no warning zone.But the sorting is crucial here. So in your picture in the answer the 61 must be at the bottom and fall in the warning zone.45,40,38,23  must fall in the so-so zone and only the 19 will be at the top of the plot as 61 is now and will be in the no warning zone.

But you can see is now properly sorted even now with.I mean 45 - 38 -40 is not sorted.I apologize for not being clear.If you can edit your answer I would appreciate it a lot.Don;;t worry about the green answer.Is yours.

No worries. I've reversed it with decreasing = TRUE.

if i wanted one line at 20% splitting the plot into two zones: warning zone below 20% and no warning zone below 20% what modifications i have to do.?From layer_data i don;t understand the pattern from the x,y,label columns

Comment out the third anno line. Change "so-so" to "no warning\nzone" in the second anno. Remove the , 5.5 from the geom_hline.

now I got it.!!!! thank you!!!! one final question: why in layer_data(p, 3) the x column as positive and negative values? in order to vertically put a line ?

The 6 negative values are the position of the 6 percentage labels on the left and similarly the 6 positive values position the 6 percentage labels on the right.

Add + scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "indianred", "lightblue", "lightgreen", "green")) as the last line.
